# Attaching @2x images with MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to specify image data scale to MFMessageComposeViewController's attachmentData? Basically I want to be able to share an image that, when unscaled, is 100x100, but should be displayed in iMessage as 50x50 with 2x scale.

Is this something that can be done by adding info to the data's EXIFDictionary? Previous attempts at setting kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight and kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth were not successful for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSData *attachmentData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[picker addAttachmentData:attachmentData
           typeIdentifier:(NSString *) kUTTypePNG
                 filename:@"attachment@2x.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

IOS would not be able to identify "attachment@2x.png" so if you wish to use attachment@2x.png then please make a copy of this image and rename it as attachmentcopy.png and paas it into filename.